# how would this grammar be parsed?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, grammar

I am studying grammars, and in the book it lists that this grammar can unambiguously parse subtraction and multiplication of numbers.
This is the grammar:

```
S -> E
E -> E - F
E -> F
F -> F / NUM
F -> NUM
NUM -> 0-9
```

say you have some input like 1 - 2 - 3. From my understanding the parse tree would go something like this:

```
    S
    |
    E
   /|\
  E - F
 /|\
E - E
....
```

Here we get into an infinite loop since E -> E - F and that E again goes to another E - F. We can't just magically know to choose to go to E->F (which is the terminal that we want).

I feel that I am understanding something incorrectly here. Can someone please explain a bit about how this actually works?

Comment: You are confusing the formal description of a grammar with the parsing process. This is perfectly understandable. In fact, the grammar you show here is what's known as left-recursive and therefore can't be parsed with LL(n) parsers like Recursive Descent for precisely the reason you mention (you would get into an infinite loop and blow the stack). However, other parsing technologies, like LR, and so on, do not have this problem and can work with grammars like yours as is.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, instead of using a [top-down parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-down_parsing) that starts at the root, a [bottom-up parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottom-up_parsing)
that starts with the leaves of the tree, in this case `1 - 2 - 3`, would be able to construct a valid parse tree like this:

```
NUM - NUM - NUM
 \     |     /
 F  -  F  - F
   \   |   /
   E - F - F
     |   /
     E - F
       |
       E
       |
       S
```